# 'Math teaching in india is robotic,make it creative'-Manjul bhargava. Then how to make it creative?

Tags: soft-question

Manjul Bhargava once said "Math teaching in India is robotic,make it creative."My question is then what is the true way to study math?I am postgraduate student from India.In our institute normally professors teach us some proofs and give us some examples to solve in homework.And the way I study is the following:Suppose I am learning Group theory.Then I read theorems and understand proofs from book(say from gallian's book) and try to solve problems given in the exercise after it.Many problems that I can not solve even after long thinking,I google it for solution.And usually for exams I prepare some specific problems and theorems.Now if this is the 'robotic' way then how should I study creatively and how should teachers teach creatively? If I can't solve particular problem then I can't stay on it for a long time because it is very time consuming and time to complete some courses is very limited.I am studying my all college courses abstract algebra,complex analysis etc in this way.Do they teach in different way in top universities?Or math is the subject for the students who are gifted and who can solve problems quickly in compare of average students?Please help me.I searched many answers on this site and on google but I did not get any satisfactory answer that's why I am asking here.
Thank you